# What information from Google's user api can I use as a key to encrypt data?

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, google-signin

What information in the user object provided by Google's sign-in API can I use as a secret or key to encrypt the data between the HTML-JS client of my website and my API?

The current structure is like this:

```
       1. HTML-JS Client
Server ----------------> Browser
  v                         v
 API <-----------------> Client
       2. HTTP Requests
```

But the HTTP requests in step 2 are non-encrypted, and I want them to be encrypted.

What I thought about:

- I have only google login information, and the user does not have a password, so I can't use that as the key.
- It should be site-specific, so the key is different on my site from some other sites that use the Google sign-in API too.
- I thought about using `access_token` but if I do that, I can't verify the google login information, and it also needs to be sent through the internet.

[image: img]

It should be obtainable from the server without the client sending it directly, for example, maybe it can be obtained from the registration process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose of this, namely, why isn't simple HTTPS sufficient?

Comment: @Peteris HTTPS only works when HTTPS is supported and properly set up, which in some situations don't support, like directly accessing it with an IP address.

Comment: Pardon my bluntness, but if you don't use HTTPS here you'll never get it right so you probably shouldn't even bother. It's best to plan this as HTTPS or nothing.

Comment: If that's the only reason, then the appropriate solution is to properly configure https and domain names so that https works, instead of trying to roll your own key exchange system, which is not a good idea. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own or other relevant questions.